# Spotlight Euro Exchange rate seems stuck to 2 weeks ago

Tags: macos, spotlight, yahoo

I use Spotlight to currency conversions several times a day.

E.g. I type into Spotlight

100 EUR to GBP
or
500 USD to CZK

However I have just noticed that the exchange rate is stuck to that of 2-3 weeks ago

For example, spotlight returns:

1 GBP = 1.34 EUR ---> should be ---> 1 GBP = 1.39 EUR

1 USD = 0.66 GBP ---> this is correct

1 EUR = 136.45 YEN ---> should be ---> 1 EUR = 132.19 YEN

The strange thing is that Spotlight's data source is Yahoo, but checking directly the exchange rate with Yahoo the correct rate is returned. So it seems like there's an issue with Spotlight.

Can anyone try it from their end? And if it's only an issue that affects me, any ideas of what to do to get it fixed?

Comment: Insane that this is still an issue in macOS 12.6. The lack of "Last update" date makes Spotlight dangerous to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting the machine sorted out the issue, but not sure if it's only at bootup that OS X refreshes the exchange rates. So the problem might happen again if I don't reboot the machine for a long time